# What plugins can I use to feature (affiliate) products on my blog (from Amazon.com)?

Tags: plugins, e-commerce

I know Amazon.com will pay affiliates (in some states, depending on tax laws) who send users to their website to buy a product. I've also seen some Wordpress sites that feature Amazon.com products with links that seem to be affilate links.

Are there any good plugins for featuring affilate products from Amazon.com (or other services?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Amazon product in a post plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/amazon-product-in-a-post-plugin/) is the best i have tried so far.

It can be used for all amazon regional websites like amazon.co.uk,amazon.fr etc